# Unable to understand a part of recursive case

Tags: python-3.x

tried:

```
def maxed(array):

    if len(array) == 2:

        return array[0] if array[0] > array[1] else array[1]

    submax = maxed(array[1:])

    return array[0] if array[0] > submax else submax
```

result:
as expected i.e. return max value from the list.

problem:
unable to understand recursive case, what if len(array) != 2 ?
how that codes working here ?

Comment: FYI: There is already a built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function.

Comment: Please update your question to make it more readable; e.g. your code. And please use full qualified complete sentences in English. Don't use just words. We are not computers but humans investing freetime supporting you learning.

Answer (score 1):

If `len(array) != 2`, that's when the recursion kicks in.  `maxed(array[1:])` passes down a list that is one element shorter than the current frame, so the array will shrink until eventually it hits the base case of `len(array) == 2`.

However, note that this implementation has one significant bug: It doesn't handle the case where `array` starts off with 0 or 1 elements.